# SQL using group_by to count users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

```
users = [
        {"id":1, "zipcode":"10031"},
        {"id":4, "zipcode":"10000"},
        {"id":2, "zipcode":"10031"},
        {"id":3, "zipcode":"10031"}
      ]
```

Hello guys. I need help a that can reduce the process of my code.
I have a users stored datas.
Were i want to achieve this in my first line of code

```
  [
    {"id":1, "zipcode":"10000", "users_count": 1}, 
    {"id":2, "zipcode":"10031", "users_count": 3},
  ]
```

My code:

`user = User.select(:zipcode).group(:zipcode).count(:id)`

> result of the above code is `{"10000"=>1, "10031"=>3}`

- so i need to get the separation of keys and values

```
  keys = user.keys
  values = user.values
```

- make a loop

```
i = 0
num = keys.length.to_i
zipcodes = []
while i < num do
  zipcode = keys[i]
  users_count = values[i]
  zipcodes[i]= zipcode , users_count
  i +=1
end
```

> result if the above code is [[10000, 1], [10031, 3]]

I want to change the result if this code
`user = User.select(:zipcode).group(:zipcode).count(:id)`

> from this
> `{"10000"=>1, "10031"=>3}`

> to this
> `[{"id":1, "zipcode":"10000", "users_count": 1},{"id":2, "zipcode":"10031", "users_count": 3}]`

#### Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your query as such,

```
user_counts = User.select(:zipcode, 'count(*) as user_count').group(:zipcode)
```

Please note that in the result that is printed on the console, the `user_count` will not be displayed, as it is not an attribute of the user model. However it is there, and can be accessed via,

```
user_counts.each do |user_count|
  puts user_count.zip_code
  puts user_count['user_count']
end
```

You can also view all the results by converting them to JSON

```
user_counts = User.select(:zipcode, 'count(*) as user_count').group(:zipcode)
puts user_counts.as_json
```

Comment: Could also call `.count` after the group and would return a hash with the zipcode and the count of them